# How zomato fetches users city and show url like zomato.com/cityname without user's consent?

Tags: javascript, php

If you open it in your browser it will not prompt you to ask for a location. [It automatically shows your city with the url](https://www.zomato.com).

Comment: may be with the IP

Comment: This can either be done with IP or https headers. Also a simple google check will find a plethora of examples for 'get web visitor location'

Comment: yes we can get user's location using IP, but I have to use some third party API like ipinfodb etc which are not reliable.